# ESLint not found for CircleCI build

Tags: javascript, node.js, circleci

I'm trying to run a simple build on CircleCI for a Node.js application:

#### config.yml

```
version: 2.0
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/app
    docker:
      - image: gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: yarn
      - save_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          paths:
            - ./node_modules
              - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - run:
          name: ESLint
          command: yarn lint
```

#### package.json

```
...
"scripts": { 
  "lint": "./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js . --ext .js --fix",
}
...
```

The error I get is:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
yarn lint
yarn run v1.16.0
$ ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js . --ext .js --fix
/bin/sh: 1: ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Exited with code 127
```

Why can't CircleCI see the `ESLint` from `node_modules`?

The `yarn lint` command works fine locally.

Comment: Does `eslint.js` have a hashbang, and the correct exec permissions, for it to run without a runner binary? Otherwise I assume you need to specify how to run it, by prefixing it with `node`?

Comment: (Are you running `./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js . --ext .js --fix` directly, or is that being run for you?)

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

like this, I can work

```
checklint:
        executor: docker-image
        steps:
            - checkout
            - node/install-packages:
                cache-path: ~/project/node_modules
                override-ci-command: npm install
            - run:
                command: npm run lint
```